# How to get EVERY App/Activity that responds to ANY URL/URI-Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Let's say that the user has the spotify, youtube, xbmc and glympse app installed.

The spotify-app responds to "spotify:album:123"-intents and the glympse-app to "glympse.com/123"-intents. Both the XBMC-app and YouTube-app respond to "youtube.com/watch?v=123"-intents.

What I want to get is every app that responds to such an intent. I don't want to give an intent for a specific URL/URI, rather I want to get every app that responds to some kind of URL/URI-intent.

If that still isn't clear enough, here is some non-working code which kind of shows what I want(except that it is only querying for a URI).

```
getPackageManager()->queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.Action_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://*")), 0)
```

Comment: i dont think you are very clear with your follow up edit too. So you want each and every app in the list which shows up when you click. you should probably be more detailed than just emphasizing a few words

Comment: I edited my question according to the criticism I got. I hope it is clear now, since my question is so far not answered at all :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to get is every app that responds to such an intent. I don't want to give an intent for a specific URL/URI, rather I want to get every app that responds to some kind of URL/URI-intent.

That is not directly possible through the Android SDK. Android can tell you activities that can respond to a *specific* `Intent`, but you cannot search through registered `<intent-filter>` objects to find all of those with a `<data>` element and an `android:scheme` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a dummy intent (that has the same format you're investigating) then using the normal PackageManage route to query which apps can handle it:

```
Intent dummy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
dummy.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4");

PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(dummy, 0);

// "list" now contains all apps that can handle a YT link
```

Comment: okay I should have been more clear on that. I want EVERY app that responds to ANY url-intent.

Comment: The thing is, that only the browsers respond to such a URL. Youtube for example only responds to youtube.com/watch?v=123 URLs...

Comment: You would have to know all the urls and loop this code for each one. ...other option i think is only to use root access, unpack every apk and parse the manifests.